# Segmentation fault при map.insert в классе c++ импортированном в Python с использованием ctypes

Tags: c++, python, map, segmentation-fault, ctypes

https://github.com/IMelker/Py-BinaryProtocolUnit

Пытался в Python импортировать самописную структуру данных реализованную на c++ и получаю ошибку сегментации при обращении к map< std::string, std::string >.insert() в методе класса.

**binary_protocol.h**

```
#ifndef __BINARY_PROTOCOL_H__
#define __BINARY_PROTOCOL_H__

#include <map>

class BinaryProtocolUnit {
public:
    BinaryProtocolUnit();
    BinaryProtocolUnit(const char* data, size_t size);
    BinaryProtocolUnit(const std::string& data);
    ~BinaryProtocolUnit();
    size_t FieldsCount() const;
    void Insert(const std::string& key, const std::string& value);
    bool IsInserted(const std::string& key) const;
    std::string Get(const std::string& key) const;
    int Remove(const std::string& key);
    void FromBinary(const char* data, size_t size);
    std::string ToBinary() const;
private:
    std::string DecodeString(const char** pointer) const;
    void EncodeString(const std::string& str, char** pointer) const;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> binary_unit_;
};

#endif
```

**binary_protocol.cpp**

```
#include "binary_protocol.h"
#include "py_binary_protocol.h"
#include <iostream> //debug

BinaryProtocolUnit::BinaryProtocolUnit() {
    binary_unit_["test1"] = "test1";
    std::cout << binary_unit_["test1"] << "\n"; // ALL OK
    std::cout << "Init protocol file. \n";
    Insert("test2","test2");
    std::cout << binary_unit_["test2"] << "\n"; //ALL OK
}

BinaryProtocolUnit::BinaryProtocolUnit(const char* data, size_t size) {
    FromBinary(data, size);
}

BinaryProtocolUnit::BinaryProtocolUnit(const std::string& data) {
    FromBinary(data.data(), data.size());
}

BinaryProtocolUnit::~BinaryProtocolUnit() {
    std::cout << "Delete protocol file. \n";
}

size_t BinaryProtocolUnit::FieldsCount() const {
    return binary_unit_.size();
}

void BinaryProtocolUnit::Insert(
        const std::string& key, const std::string& value) {
    std::cout << "Insert [" << key << " : " << value << "]. \n";
    binary_unit_[key] = value;      // SEGMENTATION FAULT
    std::cout << "Inserted [-----]. \n";
}

bool BinaryProtocolUnit::IsInserted(const std::string& key) const {
    return binary_unit_.find(key) != binary_unit_.end();
}

std::string BinaryProtocolUnit::Get(const std::string& key) const {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator
        it = binary_unit_.find(key);
    if (it != binary_unit_.end()) {
        return it->second;
    } else {
        return std::string();
    }
}

int BinaryProtocolUnit::Remove(const std::string& key) {
    return binary_unit_.erase(key);
}

void BinaryProtocolUnit::FromBinary(const char* data, size_t size) {
    const char* pointer = data;
    while (pointer < data + size) {
        std::string key = DecodeString(&pointer);
        std::string value = DecodeString(&pointer);
        Insert(key, value);
    }
}

std::string BinaryProtocolUnit::ToBinary() const {
    size_t size = binary_unit_.size() * 2 * sizeof(size_t);
    for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator
            it = binary_unit_.begin(); it != binary_unit_.end(); ++it) {
        size += it->first.size() + it->second.size();
    }
    std::string data(size, 0);
    char* pointer = const_cast<char*>(data.data());
    for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator
            it = binary_unit_.begin(); it != binary_unit_.end(); ++it) {
        EncodeString(it->first, &pointer);
        EncodeString(it->second, &pointer);
    }
    std::cout << "ToBinary [" << data << "]. \n";
    return data;
}

std::string BinaryProtocolUnit::DecodeString(const char** pointer) const {
    size_t length = *reinterpret_cast<const size_t*>(*pointer);
    *pointer += sizeof(size_t);
    std::string str(*pointer, *pointer + length);
    *pointer += length;
    return str;
}

void BinaryProtocolUnit::EncodeString(
        const std::string& str, char** pointer) const {
    *reinterpret_cast<size_t*>(*pointer) = str.size();
    *pointer += sizeof(size_t);
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), *pointer);
    *pointer += str.size();
}
```

Wrapper для дальнейшего использования с помощью `ctypes`.

**py_binary_protocol.h**

```
#include "binary_protocol.h"
#include <string>

extern "C" {
    BinaryProtocolUnit* BinaryProtocolUnit_New() {
        return new BinaryProtocolUnit();
    }

    void BinaryProtocolUnit_Del(BinaryProtocolUnit* u) {
        delete u;
    }

    size_t BinaryProtocolUnit_FieldsCount(BinaryProtocolUnit* u){
        return u->FieldsCount();
    }

    void BinaryProtocolUnit_Insert(BinaryProtocolUnit* u, const char* k, const char* v) {
        u->Insert(std::string(k), std::string(v));
    }

    bool BinaryProtocolUnit_IsInserted(BinaryProtocolUnit* u, const char* k){
        return u->IsInserted(std::string(k));
    }

    const char* BinaryProtocolUnit_Get(BinaryProtocolUnit* u, const char* k){
        return u->Get(std::string(k)).c_str();
    }

    int BinaryProtocolUnit_Remove(BinaryProtocolUnit* u, const char* k){
        return u->Remove(std::string(k));
    }

    void BinaryProtocolUnit_FromBinary(BinaryProtocolUnit* u, const char* d, size_t s){
        u->FromBinary(d, s);
    }

    const char* BinaryProtocolUnit_ToBinary(BinaryProtocolUnit* u){
        return u->ToBinary().c_str(); 
    }
}
```

Wrapper для библиотеки на python'е:

**pybpu.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
pybpu = cdll.LoadLibrary('./py_binary_protocol.so')

class BinaryProtocolUnit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_New()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_Del(self.obj)

    def FieldsCount(self):
        return pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_FieldsCount(self.obj)

    def Insert(self, key, value):
        pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_Insert(self.obj, key, value)

    def IsInserted(self, key):
        return pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_IsInserted(self.obj, key)

    def Get(self, key):
        return pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_Get(self.obj, key)

    def Remove(self, key):
        return pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_Remove(self.obj, key)

    def FromBinary(self, data, size):
        pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_FromBinary(self.obj, data, size)

    def ToBinary(self):
        return pybpu.BinaryProtocolUnit_ToBinary(self.obj)
```

Использую следующим образом:

```
from pybpu import BinaryProtocolUnit
with BinaryProtocolUnit() as bpu:
    bpu.Insert('test_key', 'test_value')
```

Библиотеку собираю следующими командами:

```
g++ -c -fPIC binary_protocol.cpp -o binary_protocol.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,py_binary_protocol.so -o py_binary_protocol.so binary_protocol.o
```

Вывод при использовании:

```
test1
Init protocol file. 
Insert [test2 : test2]. 
Inserted [-----]. 
test2
Insert [test_key : test_value]. 
Ошибка сегментирования
```

Вообще возможно такое использование классов через ctypes? Или в чем может быть ошибка.

Comment: При использовании этих функций в C++ коде, ошыбка есть?

Comment: Нет, при использовании на чистом C++ все прекрасно.

Comment: Валиться именно там где указано? Или строкой выше или ниже?

Comment: Да, причем, если сделать map статичным, то проблема записи в нее пропадает. Чтение и остальное не тестил. Не понятно почему доступ к ней нарушается, если он является приватным членом класса и даже намека на манипуляции с ней нет.

Comment: Код в `Использую следующим образом:` не выдаст результат из `Вывод при использовании:`. Вы уверены что вы то запускаете?

Comment: Я думаю что  ваша ошыбка состоит в том что вы юзаете обект после вызова деструктора

Comment: Т.е: этот код неверен `u->~BinaryProtocolUnit()` должно быть `delete u`

Comment: Это конечно же ошибка, но она не решает проблему. Залил на git все файлы для тестов https://github.com/IMelker/Py-BinaryProtocolUnit

Comment: У меня возникает такое поведение когда я юзаю объект после __exit__

Comment: Я думаю что вам нужно заменить __ exit __ на __ del __. Я так сделал и теперь не получаю ошибки